# How to repeat certain operation at specific interval?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

In my app i am having the function to repeat certain operations `every day, every week` etc. with out any user interaction. i.e if the user even not using the app the operation has to take place(Insertion of data into database). Searched a lot but couldn't get any idea about achieving this. I thought about `Local Notification`, but don't know will this be a good idea or is there any better approach to achieve this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to look into [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). think of it like unix cron for your android app. in a nutshell, you schedule an `Intent` to fire in the future. You then write a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle the intent, and do whatever you want here.

of course, the devil's in the details. pay close attention to things like offloading any time-consuming work from  your broadcast receiver to a service thread, and ensuring that you grab a wake lock before hand. these are advanced topics that can't properly be covered in a SO answer.